# getting Checkpoint VPN SSL Network Extender working in the command line

Tags: debian, vpn, checkpoint

The official Checkpoint out command line tool from CheckPoint, for setting up a SSL Network Extender VPN is not longer working from the Linux command line. It is also no longer actively supported by CheckPoint.

However, there is a promising  project, that tries to replicate the Java applet for authentication, that talks with the `snx` command line utility, called `snxconnect`.

I was trying to put `snxconnect` text utility to work in Debian Buster, doing:

```
sudo pip install snxvpn
```

and

```
export PYTHONHTTPSVERIFY=0
snxconnect -H checkpoint.hostname -U USER
```

However, it was mostly dying either with an HTTP error of:

```
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently:
```

or:

```
Got HTTP response: HTTP/1.1 302 Found
```

or:

```
Unexpected response, try again.
```

What to do about it?

PS. The EndPoint Security VPN official client is working well both in a Mac High Sierra and Windows 10 Pro.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

SNX build 800007075 from 2012, used to support the CheckPoint VPN from the Linux command line. So I tested it, and lo and behold, it still works with the latest distributions and kernel(s) 4.x/5.x.

So ultimately, my other answer in this thread holds true, if you cannot get hold of SNX build 800007075 **or** if that specific version of SNX stops working with the current Linux versions (it might happen in a near future) **or** if you need OTP support.

Presently, the solution is then installing this specific last version of SNX that **still** supports doing the VPN from the command line.

1. To install `snx` build 800007075, get it from:

```
wget https://starkers.keybase.pub/snx_install_linux30.sh?dl=1 -O snx_install.sh
```

For Debian and Debian-based 64-bit systems like Ubuntu and Linux Mint, you might need to add the 32-bit architecture:

```
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
sudo apt-get update
```

I had to install the following 32-bit packages:

```
sudo apt-get install libstdc++5:i386 libx11-6:i386 libpam0g:i386
```

Run then the `snx` installation script:

```
chmod a+rx snx_install.sh
sudo ./snx_install.sh`
```

You will have now a `/usr/bin/snx` 32-bit client binary executable. Check if any dynamic libraries are missing with:

```
sudo ldd /usr/bin/snx
```

You can only proceed to the following points when all the dependencies are satisfied.

You might need to run manually first `snx -s CheckpointURLFQDN -u USER`, before scripting any automatic use, for the signature VPN be saved at `/etc/snx/USER.db`.

2. Before using it, you create a `~/.snxrc file, using your regular user (not root)`  with the following contents:

   ```
   server IP_address_of_your_VPN
   username YOUR_USER
   reauth yes
   ```
3. For connecting, type `snx`

   $ snx
   Check Point's Linux SNX
   build 800007075
   Please enter your password:

   SNX - connected.

   ## Session parameters:

   Office Mode IP      : 10.x.x.x
   DNS Server          : 10.x.x.x
   Secondary DNS Server: 10.x.x.x
   DNS Suffix          : xxx.xx, xxx.xx
   Timeout             : 24 hours

If you understand the security risks of hard coding a VPN password in a script, you also can use it as:

```
echo 'Password' | snx
```

4. For closing/disconnecting the VPN, while you may stop/kill `snx`, the better and official way is issuing the command:

```
    $snx -d
    SNX - Disconnecting...
     done.
```

see also [Linux Checkpoint SNX tool configuration issues](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/477689/linux-checkpoint-snx-tool-configuration-issues) for some clarifications about which `snx` version to use.

5. If automating the login and accepting a new signature (and understanding the security implications), I wrote an `expect` script, which I called the script `snx_login.exp` ; not very secure, however you can automate your login, calling it with the password as an argument:

   #!/usr/bin/expect
   spawn /usr/bin/snx

   set password [lindex $argv 0]

   expect "*?assword:*"
   send -- "$password\r"

   expect {
   "o:" {
   send "y\r"
   exp_continue
   }
   eof
   }

PS. Beware `snx` does not support OTP alone, you will have to use the `snxconnect` script present on the other answer if using it.

PPS @gibies called to my attention that using an etoken, the password field gets the password plus the appended etoken and not a fixed password.

Comment: This works in arch linux using snx from aur repository.

Comment: @Met indeed, find it much later on...see the last link in this answer. Nevertheless, not sure about the legality of that AUR giving us a much older and unsupported 32 bits 2012 version of Checkpoint's snx utility, even if downloading it from a 3rd party site. I am using the same version in the accepted answer, the other is an alternative method.

Comment: @linuxatico Answer edited to replace the old download link with a working one. How did it go?

Comment: Worked for me on Ubuntu 18.04 (64-bit). I didn't execute `snx -s CheckpointURLFQDN -u USER` and executed up only to step 3.

Comment: @AmilWaduwawara "step 4" is how to disconnect, and step 5 is mainly useful for people with checkpoint clusters that present different signatures and/when the cluster is acting up. Would you please confirm whether you have IPv6 active or disabled?

Comment: Does it work with Multi factor auth?

Comment: @3nomis It seems this client works with tokens. Never tried it though, but might try it in a couple of months.

Comment: Great thanks. This works for me in Ubuntu 20.04. I don't have to face ugly windows vm for the vpn connection anymore.

Comment: @edib Yep, what originally motivated me to do this, was getting rid of the Windows corporate desktop, and installing Linux in my corporate issued machine.

Comment: snx_install_linux30.sh can still be downloaded at https://support.checkpoint.com/results/download/22824

Answer (score 13):

When working to install the Firefox official SSL VPN Extender interface in the question [VPN SSL Network Extender in Firefox](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/450131/vpn-ssl-network-extender-in-firefox/450132), I found out and solved some more pieces of the puzzle of this question.

Apparently, whilst command line usage of `snx` from checkpoint has been discontinued, the web based client as described in the linked post still works. However, there is a python command line client, that tries to replicate the Web+Java interface on top of the `snx` client, and this post is about setting it up to work.

Firstly, the `snxvp` installed from `python pip` does not work. There is an updated patched version on https://github.com/agnis-mateuss/snxvpn, that has some useful patches, including an option for ignoring unsigned and/or expired certificates, and more interestingly, being python2 **and** python3 compatible.

Furthermore, all the URLs on `snxconnect.py` have to be changed from `sslvpn/` to ``.

---

So the step-by-step instructions are roughly:

1. Firstly, installing the `snx` setup:

If in the VPN, to get the installation file, do:

```
wget --no-check-certificate https://VPN_FW_HOSTNAME/SNX/INSTALL/snx_install.sh
```

Otherwise, you will have to get it from the web interface, as described in the linked answer.

For Debian, you might need:

```
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
sudo apt-get update
```

I had to install the following:

```
sudo apt-get install libstdc++5:i386 libx11-6:i386 libpam0g:i386
```

Run then:

```
chmod a+rx snx_install.sh
sudo ./snx_install.sh`
```

You will have now a `/usr/bin/snx` 32-bit client binary executable. Check if any dynamic libraries are missing with:

```
sudo ldd /usr/bin/snx
```

You can only proceed to the following points when all the dependencies are satisfied.

Not sure if you need to run first `snx -s CheckpointURLFQDN -u USER` before using `snxconnect`, for the signature VPN be saved at `/etc/snx/USER.db`.

2. Now we have the `snxconnect` python utility. Such program tries to emulate the web interface, and more interestingly, it does not need Java to authenticate.

So to install and setup `snxconnect`, run as root:

```
apt-get -y install git make libxml2-dev libxslt1-dev zlib1g-dev
apt-get -y install python-pip
pip install pytz
git clone https://github.com/agnis-mateuss/snxvpn
git clone  git://git.code.sf.net/p/sfreleasetools/code releasetools
cd snxvpn   

Now, as for taking out the /sslvpn URL, some Checkpoint appliances need it, some do not. I am not still aware of why the difference. I need it, @WileyMarques does not.

sed -i "s/sslvpn\///g" snxconnect.py
```

. then do as root, for python3: (recommended)

```
apt-get install python3-pip python3-docutils python3-pip python3-libxml2 python3-dev python3-crypto python3-bs4
pip install rsa
make
python3 setup.py install --prefix=/usr/local
```

.  or *instead*, do as root, for python2:

```
apt-get install python-docutils python-libxml2 python-lxml python-dev python-bs4 python-beautifulsoup
sed -i "s/distutils.core/setuptools/g" setup.py
make
python setup.py install --prefix=/usr/local
```

3. After installing it, you can run as a non-privileged user:

   /usr/local/bin/snxconnect -H CheckpointURLFQDN -U USER --skip-cert --save-cookies

If all went ok, it will ask for the password, and then display:

```
SNX connected, to leave VPN open, leave this running!
```

If you are having problems getting this message, and are instead getting several times in a row, the message: "Unexpected response, try again.", do the Firefox method, and Disconnect and logout properly, waiting a couple of minutes before trying the `snxconnect` command again.

4. The cookie(s) file will be created at ~/.snxcookies, after a successful usage.

After the VPN being established, you can check with `ip address` or `ifconfig` you have now a `tunsnx` interface:

```
$ ip addr show dev tunsnx
14: tunsnx: <POINTOPOINT,MULTICAST,NOARP,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UNKNOWN group default qlen 100
    link/none
    inet 10.x.x.x peer 10.x.x.x/32 scope global tunsnx
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::acfe:8fce:99a4:44b7/64 scope link stable-privacy
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

`ip route` will show you also new routes going through the `tunsnx` interface.

5. For closing/disconnecting the VPN, while you may stop/kill `snxconnect`, the better and official way is issuing the command:

   $snx -d

   SNX - Disconnecting...
   done.

---

In addition, I also found out:

- `snxconnect` seems to behave better when disconnecting the previous VPN connection and logging out in the official web interface *if there is some strange problem* (have to try doing `snx -d` to see if it produces the same result);
- PYTHONHTTPSVERIFY=0 only affects the python2 version;
- if the web interface is doing an HTML redirect to a secondary CheckPoint location, pointing directly to that redirected hostname, holds better results;
- if the certificates of the firewalls are self-signed (they often are) the --skip-cert option has to be used, or authentication will fail;
- for not having so many problems re-authenticating, had to use --save-cookies to use authentication cookies, while the user is logged in in the remote VPN point (it has a timeout of x hours);
- as described in the last question, for the script to work, the option "When signing-in launch SSL Network Extender" has to be changed to "automatically";
- 7776/TCP in localhost has to be free, for `snx` to own it, as `snxconnect` talks with `snx` using it;
- the hostname passed to `snxconnect`/`snx` is handled as a virtual host, and as such you cannot use directly the VPN IP address;
- instaling a 32-bit architecture seems to be a requirement to run the `snx_install.sh` script;
- you might choose to run as `python2` as a trade-off for less space, however as python2 is being phased out, `snxconnect` in a near future might not support it;
- from using the web client interface, it is clear I need to patch/delete all `/sslvpn` strings , as my URLs do not start with `/sslvpn`. I would check your particular case. I have absolutely no idea whether the presence of that string in the code is due to an old version, would love some feedback;
- in `snxconnect` the CheckPoint hostname has to be the exact name the webinterface is showing you once authenticated in there, as it is a web virtual host. Otherwise, you won´t succeed on establishing the VPN;
- The first time `snx` is used, a file with the signature of the VPN/Checkpoint server will be created at `/etc/snx/USER.db`;
- If you need to use OTP from the command line, you have to use `snxconnect` as `snx` alone does not support it.

Comment: Regarding the removal of '/sslvpn' strings. The server I connect to has it on the URL, so I didn't that step. Interesting to point this on the answer, since it may happen to other people.

Comment: @WileyMarques Thanks for the feedback, I already suspected it would be different for some, also because in the github/pip version the URL is there.

Comment: My VPN uses multiauthentication, so I found I had to add `-MC yes` to the `snxconnect` command to get it to work in my case. Works like a charm now, thanks so much for this, Rui!

Comment: Excellent! It worked as a charm!