# Checkpoint SNX in Ubuntu 18.04 via terminal

Tags: ubuntu, python, vpn, ssl, authentication

I am trying to connect to Checkpoint VPN's snx module, but I am unsuccessful. After entering the password, it no longer returns, not even the error.

I followed these steps for installation: [getting Checkpoint VPN SSL Network Extender working in the command line](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/450229/getting-checkpoint-vpn-ssl-network-extender-working-in-the-command-line).